# Node Index.js does nothing

Tags: node.js

NodeJs is installed on a new MacBook first using brew and then with installer for MacOs.  NextJs projects are running fine. But when I try to create an express project, and run
 `node server.js`
nothing working. Then I tried with a test project. Only one file, index.js with nothing but  `console.log("test")`

From terminal I run  `node index.js` did not get any output even no error.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you sure node is installed? What do you get if you run `node --version`?

Comment: node -v
v20.10.0

Comment: share your index.js or server.js file content

Comment: Are you in the right folder? Also, just a tip, but `nvm` is a good solution for installing and managing node on your mac.

Comment: Resolved! The issue was simply a matter of saving the file. I had assumed that Visual Studio Code would automatically save it, but it turns out manual saving was needed.